# Vertical centering with multirow and tables

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to figure something out that I can't find the answer to.

I am trying to create a table where some cells in a row need to have multiple rows.  I thought "multirow" would allow me to do this, which it does, but it incorrectly vertically centers the data that spans multiple rows. See the attached figure - it ends up being too high.[image]

I realize that in the example I sent, I can just use 3 rows with the top and bottom being empty but in the case of having an even number of split rows, that method isn't possible. I also looked at the documentation for multirow and they specify that there is a finetuning parameter where you can adjust its height manually. I do not want to do this because if I am off even by a little bit it won't line up. Plus I figured there would be a better way.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % shouldn't you be using 'utf8'?
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}

\setlength{\textheight}{9in} % Height of the main body of the text
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in} % .5" margin on top of page
\setlength{\headsep}{.5in}  % space between header and top of body
\addtolength{\headsep}{-\headheight} % See The LaTeX Companion, p 85
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}  % space between footer and bottom of body
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} % width of the body of the text
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in} % 1.25" margin on the left for odd pages
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in} % 1.25"  margin on the right for even pages

% Marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{.75in} % width of marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.125in} % space between marginal notes and text
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption[A caption]{A caption} 
\label{tab-brachy-review}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
        M{0.1}M{0.14}M{0.13}M{0.15}M{0.13}M{0.14}M{0.085}M{0.125}}

    Refs                     & Site                   & Method                  & Sample Size        & fractions        & Delay (days)       & BF and Perm & test       \\ \midrule
    Janssen                  & Te                 & 1                  & 23                 & 25 / 5                     & Day 5\textsuperscript{a} & Increase    & NSC      \\ \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Coolens} & \multirow{3}{*}{Li} & \multirow{3}{*}{2} & \multirow{3}{*}{6} & \multirow{3}{*}{30-54 / 6} & Day 3\textsuperscript{a} & Increase    & Increase \\ \cmidrule{6-8}
                             &                        &                         &                    &                            & 30                       & Decrease    & NSC      \\ \cmidrule{6-8}
                             &                        &                         &                    &                            & 60                       & Decrease    & NSC      \\ \cmidrule{6-8}
    Janssen                  & Te                 & 1                 & 23                 & 25 / 5                     & Day 5\textsuperscript{a} & Increase    & NSC      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to know what exactly a `booktab` is doing different from a plain tabular. Specifically, two spaces are added below and above rules, `\belowrulesep=.65ex` and `\aboverulesep=.4ex`. These additional vertical spaces spoil the work of `\multirow`, happily though, as you mentioned, there is an additional option for `\multirow` which can be used to compensate for this.

The rule is like this: if you have `n` rows in `\multirow`, so you need to lower the contents by `n/2 * (0.65ex + 0.4ex) = n/2 * 1.05ex`, or simply `0.525*n`. In our case, this is `0.525*3ex = 1.5750ex`. So, simply do the math or use `\dimexpr` to calculate this dimension and add its negative to the option for `\multirow`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % shouldn't you be using 'utf8'?
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}

\setlength{\textheight}{9in} % Height of the main body of the text
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in} % .5" margin on top of page
\setlength{\headsep}{.5in}  % space between header and top of body
\addtolength{\headsep}{-\headheight} % See The LaTeX Companion, p 85
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}  % space between footer and bottom of body
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} % width of the body of the text
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in} % 1.25" margin on the left for odd pages
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in} % 1.25"  margin on the right for even pages

% Marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{.75in} % width of marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.125in} % space between marginal notes and text
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption[A caption]{A caption} 
\label{tab-brachy-review}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
        M{0.1}M{0.14}M{0.13}M{0.15}M{0.13}M{0.14}M{0.085}M{0.125}}

    Refs                               & Site                          & Method                       & Sample Size                  & fractions                            & Delay (days)             & BF and Perm & test     \\ \midrule
    Janssen                            & Te                            & 1                            & 23                           & 25 / 5                               & Day 5\textsuperscript{a} & Increase    & NSC      \\ \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}[-1.575ex]{Coolens} & \multirow{3}{*}[-1.575ex]{Li} & \multirow{3}{*}[-1.575ex]{2} & \multirow{3}{*}[-1.575ex]{6} & \multirow{3}{*}[-1.575ex]{30-54 / 6} & Day 3\textsuperscript{a} & Increase    & Increase \\ \cmidrule{6-8}
                                       &                               &                              &                              &                                      & 30                       & Decrease    & NSC      \\ \cmidrule{6-8}
                                       &                               &                              &                              &                                      & 60                       & Decrease    & NSC      \\ \cmidrule{6-8}
    Janssen                            & Te                            & 1                            & 23                           & 25 / 5                               & Day 5\textsuperscript{a} & Increase    & NSC      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Awesome thanks that fixed it. Two other relataed question (I am very new to latex). How do you use the \dimexpr? and also, is there a way to change those two properties you mentioned to something else for this tex document?

Comment: You can calculate this by, e.g., `\newcommand{\LOW}{-\the\numexpr3/2*1.05ex\relax}` and use the option as `[\LOW]`. Also, you can change the values for `\belowrulesep = .65ex` and `\aboverulesep = .4ex` by putting any value other than `.65ex` and `.4ex`. For example, you can do `\belowrulesep = 0ex` outside the table, this will be global.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I wanted to try and set up a "dynamic" command so that it would be automatic. I created the command

\newcommand{\LOW}[1]{-\the\numexpr#1/2*1.05\relax} and tried using that by  calling it:

...[\LOW{3}]{Coolens \LOW{3}}

in the table but this resulted in a value of 2.05 (If i remember correctly) being displayed. In addition, it was off center (corresponding to an incorrect value being assigned). I am not sure why this is. 

Thanks for your help so far